# Stylie Wpf MenuItem based on model type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ConfigVM, that may be inherited by other view models, like BooleanConfigVM (on/off) or SingleSelectConfigVM (select one from list).

I would like to make list from them. What is correct way of doing so in wpf?

I tried to store them in external ResourceDictionary, experimented with Styles, DataTemplates and Triggers. My problem is that I need to bind properties on menu item (like IsCheckable, ItemsSource, IsChecked etc.) to my view model, not on my data template! I made styles that do so with setters, but cannot apply them in xaml only for some reason.
Example style:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuConfigEntryBase" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SingleSelectConfigStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ConfigStyleBase}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Values}" />
</Style>
```

Also I dislike fact, that such binding is done in styles. I think that DataTemplate should care about data, and styles about looks. Currently I am setting ItemsSource in styles that looks weird.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current `Style` which you posted ?

Comment: It works if I put `<MenuItem>` with this style in TreeView, but I cannot get it to work from resources file. Style itself works fine, just I wanted to ilustrate what I dislike about it (directly below snippet).